# Automate file downloading

Tags: selenium

For automating downloading with Selenium, how can one set preference for downloading "**.do**" extension files in Mozilla Firefox? What would be the  **MIME** type of this kind of file? I have written the following lines of code but my script isn't exactly working:

```
FirefoxProfile ff = new FirefoxProfile();
ff.setPreference("network.proxy.type", ProxyType.AUTODETECT.ordinal());
String key1 ="browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk";
String value1="text/do";
ff.setPreference(key1, value1);
String key3= "browser.download.dir";
String value3= "d:\\";
ff.setPreference(key3, value3);
driver=new FirefoxDriver(ff);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.Below is my code

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", ProxyType.AUTODETECT.ordinal());

    profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);

    profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","C:\\Test");

    profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
            "application/x-jar,application/application/vnd.android.package-archive," +
            "application/msword,application/x-rar-compressed,application/octet-stream,application/csv,text/csv,text/html,text/do,application/do");

    driver=new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup a Firefox profile with a download location. Then you could validate with file system that file is correct using java utils. As far as MIME type when you download a sample .do you can figure out type from there.

Comment: I have attached my code above.Can you suggest any change in that code